# How to use StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject with ts, react-native and styled components?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I am trying to make this code to work

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Container = styled.View`
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   ${StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject};
`;
```

Unfortunately typescript is complaining with the following error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'AbsoluteFillStyle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<ViewProps & ContainerProps, any>>'.
  Type 'AbsoluteFillStyle' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<string | number | false | Styles | StyledComponentClass<any, any, any> | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<ViewProps & ContainerProps, any>> | ReadonlyArray<FlattenInterpolation<ThemedStyledProps<ViewProps & ContainerProps, any>>> | null | undefined>'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'AbsoluteFillStyle'.
```

Any help is appriciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The following syntax is supposed to work to use a CSS properties object with styled-components, though I haven't tested it myself:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Container = styled.View({
   ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   justifyContent: center,
   alignItems: center
})
```

Mixing a CSS properties object with an interpolated string on the same call to `styled` currently isn't supported.  See [this issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1762) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with something like this. refer doc link [clik here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#absolutefillobject)

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: center,
    alignItems: center
  },
});
```

Comment: That's the standard way of doing this in RN, but here I need to use styled-components